# Accessing files outside of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm using mina (https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina) as deployement tool for my rails app.
I use Carrierwave gem to handle uploads inside my app.

The uploads dir is shared through deployments and is copied to myapp/production/shared/public/uploads.

Mina creates a symlink from myapp/public/uploads to myapp/production/shared/public/uploads where the files are stored.

When I attach a file to my models, it get saved corectly but when trying to display it, I get a 403 error.

In apache, my app is configure to start from
`<Directory "/home/jigger/rails/myapp/production/current/public">`

Is the issue coming from here?
How can I give access to the myapp/shared/public/uploads dir to apache/ my rails app?

thanks for your help

The full virtual directory config:

`<Directory "/home/jigger/rails/myapp/production/current/public">
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: What's an example URI path that's generating the 403 error?

Comment: hi,
for example:
/uploads/event/image/465/square_13662250_1238352296217366_1464520080533988705_o.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions on your `myapp/production/shared/public/uploads` directory and all subdirectories that carrierwave is creating, they should be at least user `rwx` but depending on your setup, you may also need group `rwx`.

Then also check the permissions that the files are being created with (this will depend on your umask and/or permissions configuration for carrierwave), you need user and maybe group to be at least `rw` for the file itself.

Finally, it's possible that you have misconfigured apache to deny read access on that `/uploads` virtual directory.  You don't need to configure anything for that directory, so if you have anything then remove it entirely.

#### Update

Since adding your apache config the problem is obvious, you've set `Options None` which means that apache will NOT follow symlinks.  You need to remove that line so it uses the default, or add the default in explicitly:

```
Options FollowSymlinks
```

Comment: Ok.

production/shared/public$ ls -al uploads/ gives me:

drwxr-xr-x 3 jigger jigger 4096 juil. 19 22:22 event

Comment: There are too many variables for me to successfully translate that into anything meaningful, if you're not able to navigate my instructions above then please find an ops person who can.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't format my comment properly. I checked the rights and even forced all the shared directory to be writable and readable to all, but nothing changed. I added the virtual directory config to my question.

Comment: Ok, problem is obvious now, let me amend my answer.

Comment: And sorry for my english. I'm French :D

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

In my apache virtual dir config, I had to allow apache to serve files which are not inside the app root, by adding the directive

Options FollowSymlinks.

Thanks @smathy for your time